# TypeScript Array of objects with reference and push() method

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, interface

Lately I have found a snag in my code. I'm working with my custom objects and arrays of them. I have found one case in which push() method is working and the other one in which it isn't.

First case (working ok):

```
class MyObject{
  private reference: d3.Selection<SVGElement>;

  public constructor(ref: d3.Selection<SVGElement>){
    this.reference = ref;
  }
}

interface ViewModel{
  objects: MyObject[] 
}

class MyApp{
  private root: d3.Selection<SVGElement>

  private viewModel: ViewModel;

  constructor(options: Type){
    this.root = options.root
    this.viewModel.objects.push(new MyObject(this.root))
  }
}
```

Second case (not working):

```
class MyObject{
  private reference: d3.Selection<SVGElement>;

  public constructor(ref: d3.Selection<SVGElement>){
    this.reference = ref;
  }
}

class MyApp{
  private root: d3.Selection<SVGElement>

  private objects: MyObject[];

  constructor(options: Type){
    this.root = options.root
    this.objects.push(new MyObject(this.root)) //seems to freeze the whole program
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Michal

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialised your `objects` array yet:

```
private objects: MyObject[] = [];
```

That might work :)

<sub>Although, you have not initialised your `viewModel` in your 'working' example. So I suppose you posted a stripped version of your code?</sub>

Comment: Yep :) Exactly that one. Thanks a lot !